# move_uploaded_file() is not storing my image file in the required destination folder

Tags: php, move-uploaded-file

I have a folder called `uploads` inside my root directory (`C:\xampp\htdocs`). I am trying to implement the php function `move_uploaded_file()`, to store my image file inside that folder. This is my code:

```
$folder="/uploads";
try{
   $moved=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][0],$folder.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'][0]);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();  //shows nothing
}
if($moved)
    echo "Moved to location successfully";
else
    echo $folder.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'][0]; // shows /uploads/business-man.png
```

I have double checked the `file_name`, the `tmp_name`. They are correct. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is your error? Can you check $moved from var_dump etc? What is returning? Can you also wrap it with try catch block?

Comment: `var_dump` shows the output `bool(false)`

Comment: what is $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][0] ? returning

Comment: `C:\xampp\tmp\php7E63.tmp`

Comment: Did you try to use the absolute path for $folder?

Comment: So when you join them with $folder var it should be uploads/C:\xampp\tmp\php7E63.tmp ? Can you check and var_dump your second parameter for move_uploaded_file?

Comment: Like `$folder='C:/xampp/htdocs/uploads/'`?

Comment: @Abhishek Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display to enable error reporting to show all errors. Also add the output of `var_dump($_FILES);` to your question.

Comment: There is no error in `$_FILES`. I can easily fetch all the information.